# Stargate Dialing Condundrums

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In season two of Stargate there is an episode called "The Fifth Race" where Jack is implanted with Ancient knowledge that leads him to the Aguards. During this episode Captain Carter leads SG1 to a planet where they dial in to SGC to say a second, closer and hotter sun has risen and they will die if they stay there but they can not come back because the Dial Home Device (DHD) is shutting down half way through address and not establishing a wormhole. Because of Jack's ancient knowledge imprint he draws out schematics for the DHD and how to fix it. SGC dials SG1 and sends through the plans to fix it. They fix it and come home.

My question is; why the hell don't they come back when they established a wormhole to say "We can not establish a wormhole?" OR why not walk through the wormhole after SGC establish it to send them protective equipment or plans? I did not think that it was strictly I dial and only I can go through, if it is supposed to work like a telephone what's to say I can't dial you and you walk through to me??

Comment: Related; [In Stargate why can you go only in one direction through the gate but radio signals can go both ways?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2943/in-stargate-why-can-you-go-only-in-one-direction-through-the-gate-but-radio-sign)

Comment: Stargate FAQ: http://www.gateworld.net/the_stargate_faq.shtml

Answer (score 11):

SG1 didn't establish an *outgoing* wormhole to complain about not being to open a wormhole, Hammond ordered one to be established *from* Stargate Command when SG-1 failed to follow established procedure and check in.

> [Lt. Simmons enters the office.]
>
> **SIMMONS:** *Sir, SG-1 did not return the probe on schedule.*
>
> **HAMMOND:** *Let's open the Gate and try to make contact.*
>
> **SIMMONS:** *Yes, Sir.*
>
> Hammond rises from his chair and precedes Simmons out of the office.]
>
> **INT—SGC—EMBARKATION ROOM**
>
> [The wormhole establishes.]
>
> <sub><sup>[SG1: The Fifth Race - Transcript](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/2.16_%22The_Fifth_Race%22_Transcript)</sup></sub>

Since the wormhole is coming *from* Earth, the team can't use it to return back. It's a well-established principle that **wormholes are only useful for one-way travel,** other than radio.