# Is the Stargate half duplex or one way?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Is the Stargate half duplex or one way? I know it can send radio signals both ways but doesn’t seem like it can send and receive matter. It seems only the dialer can transfer matter.

In “The Fifth Race” Gen Hammond he gives this impression. Season 2 Episode 15 -22:00.

Comment: Does anyone want to mention the implications on the original cut of the pilot 

Comment: Something is missing in that final paragraph.

Comment: And how many stop bits and parity bits are used?

Comment: The gate goes both ways. How else could the team return?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2943/13875

Comment: @ThePopMachine in that question he asks what about Apophis remote dialing a gate. How do you know what direction to send the matter stream through? Is there a traffic light to indicate incoming or outgoing? In other words could it be bidirectional until a transfer is started?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts:   It is demonstrated all the time that you can only dial **out** a gate.   You could properly find 50 references to this over the series.   It a basic premise of so many of the stories.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is stated on multiple occasions that wormhole travel is uni-directional for normal matter. There are exceptions for radio waves which can travel freely in both directions, allowing the SGC to communicate with their offworld teams.

> **CARTER:** *Well, even though the wormhole only allows matter to travel one way we are able to transmit radio signals back and forth.*
>
> <sub><sup>SG1: Watergate</sup></sub>

Various other electro-magnetic phenomena can also travel through an outgoing wormhole back to its source.

> McKAY: *No, you're both horribly wrong, both of you, but you gave me an idea. We know that certain waves can travel in both directions through a wormhole. Uh, radio signals, for one...We send a massive EM pulse back through the wormhole, knock out whatever it is that's making this happen on the other end.*
>
> <sub><sup>SG1: Redemption, Part 2</sup></sub>

As can intense gravity fields.

> **SIMMONS:** It's an outgoing wormhole. Nothing can come through this way.
>
> **CARTER:** Except for the black hole's gravity. Now close it! That's an order!
>
> <sub><sup>SG1: A Matter of Time</sup></sub>